# What's the best practice or design pattern for user registration?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

We have a big portal that needs user registration to allow them use its services.  It's already done in .NET and SOL Server 2005. We are in the phase now of discovering all the problems of the current registration system to build a new robust and flexible one that can be extended easily and can be more usable for all services.

What are some best practices and design patterns to rebuild this using good architectural practices?

Comment: Can you name some problems on MS User Registration ?

Comment: This can be closed as "too broad".

Comment: Trying again to close this as too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is really too open ended to give a good answer to.  However, I would recommend using the built-in Membership stuff: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw292whz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can start with the built-in membership component. You can modify that if you need to by modifying the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Rhino.Secuirty http://weblogs.asp.net/arturtrosin/archive/2009/04/02/rhino-tools-rhino-security-guide.aspx.

It takes a while to get used to but once you're there you'll see its beauty.

I guess open ended questions receive open ended answers :).

Comment: Ugh.. that's a lot of code to include in your project for only a user membership.  If you're already using NHibernate and Windosor, I suppose it would be fine.. but if you're not, it makes Rhino Security a tough call to make.

Comment: If you're building a medium size project without using an OR/M and an IoC you're quite definitely *writing* way too much code. Way better referencing one or two more libraries than writing loads of generic code.

Comment: 1) "probably" not "definitely" and  2) not using NHibernate and Windsor is not the same as not using ORM and IoC. Apart from that, I agree (-:

Comment: I agree with Murph.  If you're already invested in some other framework, then Rhino seems to add a ton of extra cruft.  My problem with many of these frameworks is they require to use a specific other set of technologies, and that is unlikely to fit most peoples needs.

Comment: @Mystere "build a new robust flexible one that can be extended easily and can be more usable for all services" ... made me think the objective was more than "username == 'username' && password == 'password'" which is what most projects usually end up requiring. About using frameworks with dependencies, I think the question is specific to each project with a number of factors being at play.