# Design Patterns for User Registration process

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

During an interview I was asked to create sample application for user registration/login with the following requirements

- Should have layered architecture
- Use Design patterns (At least 2)
- Abstract programming
- Basic validation

I completed this assignment without using design patterns. What design pattern would have been appropriate for user registration?

This question maybe a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752509)

In that answer they have suggested using Microsoft Membership Provider, but is it not possible to implement the layered architecture?

Comment: What kind of patterns do you want: GoF kind of patterns, architectural patterns or PoEAA type of patterns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really hate when some one forces me to use a design pattern because they should emerge out of design.

Anyway, if I had to use something just for the sake of using I would go with the [Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) for structuring the data access layer and would use the [Separated Interface](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/separatedInterface.html) design pattern mentioned by Martin Fowler to implement that, and to stuff in another one, I would go for the [Layer Supertype](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/layerSupertype.html) pattern and make a base class for all domain layer entities such as user, admin, login_info, etc.